# Creating a Deck of Cards using linked list

Tags: c, visual-studio-2015, linked-list, playing-cards

I can't seem to figure this out. For some reason my linked list is not creating a deck of cards or even creating one node. If anybody could help I would really appreciate it. All of my code is below. If you could tell me what I am doing wrong and point me in the right direction that would be very helpful.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#define SPADE "\x06"
#define CLUB "\x05"
#define DIAMONDS "\x04"
#define HEART "\x03"

typedef struct node {
    int face_val;
    char suit[10];
    struct card_s * next;
} card;


void add_card(card **headp, card **tailp, int face, char suit) {

    char suit2[10] = "Test";

    *tailp = (card*)malloc(sizeof(card));
    card *temp = (card*)malloc(sizeof(card));
    temp->face_val = face;
    temp->suit[10] = &suit2;
    strcpy(temp->suit, suit2);

    if (*headp == NULL) {
        *headp = temp;
        (*headp)->next = *tailp;
    }

    else {
        (*tailp)->face_val = temp->face_val;
        (*tailp)->suit[10] = temp->suit;
        (*tailp)->next = malloc(sizeof(card));
        *tailp = (*tailp)->next;
    }
    return;
}


void create_deck(card **headp, card **tailp) {

    int i = 1;


    while (i <= 13) {
        int j = 1;
        while (j <= 4) {


            if (j == 1) {
                add_card(headp,tailp,i,SPADE);
            }
            if (j == 2) {
                add_card(headp,tailp,i,HEART);
            }
            if (j == 3) {
                add_card(headp,tailp,i,DIAMONDS);
            }
            if (j == 4) {
                add_card(headp,tailp,i,CLUB);
            }

            j++; 
        }
        i++;
    }
    return;
}


int main(void) {

    card *headp=NULL;
    card *tailp=NULL;

    create_deck(&headp,&tailp);

}
```

Comment: When you write code, start with something simple that works perfectly, then add complexity a little at a time. Try writing a linked list of *numbers*, before you introduce all the complication of playing cards.

Comment: What, exactly, were your trying to do with `temp->suit[10] = &suit2;`?

Comment: Just using the suit input in that function wasn't working so I thought I would have to initialize the string to something so I created suit2 and I figured I could just switch it to what I want it to be using strcpy. So basically, I added that in to try anything to get it work

Comment: `, char suit)` --> `, const char *suit)`

Comment: `temp->next = NULL; if (*headp == NULL) {
        *tailp = *headp = temp;
    } else {
        *tailp = (*tailp)->next = temp;
    }`

Comment: To add one card you allocate memory for three cards. That's a red flag right there, think about that. It also seems like you're trying to optimize by passing around the head and tail, but you're struggling with a basic linked list. I'd suggest keeping it as simple as possible.

Comment: `struct card_s * next;` --> `struct node * next;`

Comment: when calling any of the heap allocation functions: (malloc, calloc, realloc) 1) the returned value has type `void*` so can be assigned to any other pointer.  Casting just clutters the code, making understanding, debugging, etc much more difficult.  2)  always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful

Comment: the `SPADE`, `CLUB`, `DIAMOND`, and `HEART` are strings, but are passed to a function expecting a single char.  Suggest re-defining them similar to: #define SPADE 0x06, etc

Comment: nothing from the `math.h` header file is being used in the posted code.  including header files those contents are not used is a poor programming practice and can create problems later on.

Comment: this line: `temp->suit[10] = &suit2;` is assigning the address of a parameter (that is on the local stack) to one past the end of the array `suit[]`   Perhaps you meant: `temp->suit[0] = suit;`   This line: `strcpy(temp->suit, suit2);` is pure nonsense.  Suggest elimination of that statement.

Answer (score 0):

As others pointed out in comments you were doing lots of mistakes like allocating card three times instead of one, passing a string literal into a char parameter and overwriting the `tailp` right away without checking it's previous value, After all this is what which your add_card element would manipulate for most of the time. I tested your code and i corrected some of the mistakes. I was able to see cards :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#define SPADE "SPADE"
#define CLUB "CLUB"
#define DIAMONDS "DIAMOND"
#define HEART "HEART"

typedef struct node {
    int face_val;
    char suit[10];
    struct node * next;
} card;


void add_card(card **headp, card **tailp, int face, const char* suit) {
    card *temp = (card*)malloc(sizeof(card)); // allocate new card
    temp->face_val = face; // assign face val
    strcpy(temp->suit, suit); // assign suit

    if (*headp == NULL) {
        *headp = temp;
        *tailp = temp;
    }
    else {
        (*tailp)->next = temp;
        *tailp = temp;
    }
}


void create_deck(card **headp, card **tailp) {
    int i = 1;
    while (i <= 13) {
        int j = 1;
        while (j <= 4) {
            if (j == 1) 
                add_card(headp,tailp,i,SPADE);
            if (j == 2) 
                add_card(headp,tailp,i,HEART);
            if (j == 3) 
                add_card(headp,tailp,i,DIAMONDS);
            if (j == 4) 
                add_card(headp,tailp,i,CLUB);
            j++; 
        }
        i++;
    }
}

void printDeck(card *curNode) {
    while(curNode != NULL) {
      printf("face val : %d, SUIT : %s\n", curNode->face_val, curNode->suit);
      curNode = curNode->next;
    }
}


int main(void) {
    card *headp=NULL;
    card *tailp=NULL;
    create_deck(&headp,&tailp);
    printDeck(headp);
}
```

Besides that, you can learn more about linked lists from a [here](http://quiz.geeksforgeeks.org/linked-list-set-1-introduction/).

Answer (score 0):

here is a proposed version of the code

1. it cleanly compiles
2. it performs appropriate error checking
3. it does NOT `cleanup` when an error occurs, however, it should
4. it properly defines the suit values as individual characters
5. it corrects the parameter list for `add_card()`
6. it documents what is used from each header file
7. it does NOT `#include` header files those contents are not used
8. it separates the struct definition from the associated `typedef`
9. it corrects the struct definition
10. it removes unneeded code
11. it properly generates the linked list
12. it properly generates a circular linked list
13. it properly sets the tail pointer to point to the last entry in  the linked list
14. it uses `for()` statements rather than the 'clunky' `while()` statements
15. it uses meaningful names rather than hardcoded 'magic' numbers
16. if follows the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*
17. it consistently indents the code, indenting after every opening brace '{'. unindenting before every closing brace '}'.
18. it separates code blocks (for, if, else, while, do..while, switch, case, default) via a single blank line.
19. it separate functions, etc by 2 blank lines.

And now the code:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>    // perror()
#include <stdlib.h>   // malloc(), exit(), EXIT_FAILURE
//#include <math.h>

#define MAX_SUITS 4
#define MAX_CARDS_IN_SUIT 13

#define SPADE 0x06
#define CLUB 0x05
#define DIAMONDS 0x04
#define HEART 0x03

struct node
{
    int face_val;
    char suit;
    struct node * next;
};
typedef struct node card;


// prototypes
void add_card(card **headp, card **tailp, int face, char suit);
void create_deck(card **headp, card **tailp);


void add_card(card **headp, card **tailp, int face, char suit)
{
    card *temp = malloc(sizeof(card));
    if( !temp )
    {
        perror( "malloc failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, malloc successful

    temp->face_val = face;
    temp->suit = suit;
    temp->next = *headp;

    if (*headp == NULL)
    {
        *headp = temp;
        *tailp = temp;
    }

    else
    {
        (*tailp)->next = temp;
        *tailp = temp;
    }
} // end function: add_card


void create_deck(card **headp, card **tailp)
{
    for ( int i=1; i <= MAX_CARDS_IN_SUIT; i++ )
    {
        for( int j=1; j <= MAX_SUITS; j++ )
        {
            switch( j )
            {
                case 1:
                    add_card(headp,tailp,i,SPADE);
                    break;

                case 2:
                    add_card(headp,tailp,i,HEART);
                    break;

                case 3:
                    add_card(headp,tailp,i,DIAMONDS);
                    break;

                case 4:
                    add_card(headp,tailp,i,CLUB);
                    break;
            } // end switch
        } // end for each suit
    } // end for each card in suit
} // end function: create_deck


int main(void)
{

    card *headp=NULL;
    card *tailp=NULL;

    create_deck(&headp,&tailp);
} // end function: main
```